# Dominated convergence Theorem

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, integration, limits-and-convergence

I am struggling to understand the proof in the paper, [Learning Temporal Evolution of Spatial Dependence with
Generalized Spatiotemporal Gaussian Process Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1901.04030.pdf).

Theorem 2.1 in the page 33 uses dominated convergence theorem (DCT) to show that the below series converges in $L^1(\mathcal{Z} \times \mathcal{Z})$ sense where $\mathcal{Z} = \mathbf{X} \times \mathcal{T}$
$$\sum_{l=1}^\infty \lambda_l(t) \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{T}}(t, t')\lambda_l(t')\phi_l(\mathbf{x}) \phi_l(\mathbf{x}')$$
by showing that
$$\sum_{l=1}^\infty \Bigg\vert \int_{\mathcal{Z}} \int_{\mathcal{Z}} \lambda_l(t) \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{T}}(t, t')\lambda_l(t')\phi_l(\mathbf{x}) \phi_l(\mathbf{x}')d\mathbf{z}d\mathbf{z}' \Bigg\vert < \infty$$
where $\mathbf{z} = (\mathbf{x}, t)$ and $\mathbf{z}' = (\mathbf{x}', t')$.

However, for me, the direct application of DCT would need the boundedness of
$$\sum_{l=1}^\infty \int_{\mathcal{Z}} \int_{\mathcal{Z}} \Big\vert \lambda_l(t) \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{T}}(t, t')\lambda_l(t')\phi_l(\mathbf{x}) \phi_l(\mathbf{x}') 
\Big\vert d\mathbf{z}d\mathbf{z}' < \infty $$
with a monotone sequence of dominating functions
$$\sum_{l=1}^L \Big\vert \lambda_l(t) \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{T}}(t, t')\lambda_l(t')\phi_l(\mathbf{x}) \phi_l(\mathbf{x}') 
\Big\vert \ge \Bigg\vert \sum_{l=1}^L \lambda_l(t) \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{T}}(t, t')\lambda_l(t')\phi_l(\mathbf{x}) \phi_l(\mathbf{x}') 
\Bigg\vert \quad \forall L \in \mathbf{N}$$
to have the below condition
$$\int_{\mathcal{Z}} \int_{\mathcal{Z}} \sum_{l=1}^L \Big\vert \lambda_l(t) \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{T}}(t, t')\lambda_l(t')\phi_l(\mathbf{x}) \phi_l(\mathbf{x}') 
\Big\vert d\mathbf{z}d\mathbf{z}'$$
$$ \xrightarrow[]{L\rightarrow\infty} \sum_{l=1}^\infty \int_{\mathcal{Z}} \int_{\mathcal{Z}} \Big\vert \lambda_l(t) \mathcal{C}_{\mathcal{T}}(t, t')\lambda_l(t')\phi_l(\mathbf{x}) \phi_l(\mathbf{x}') 
\Big\vert d\mathbf{z}d\mathbf{z}' < \infty $$

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.